# How to customize php-markdown link syntax

Tags: php, markdown

Links can be defined through:

```
[foo](http://foo)
//or
[foo][1]


[1]:http://foo
```

How do you customize [php-markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) so you can choose whether it would be `rel="nofollow"` or not? Something like

`[foo](!http://foo "this is the title")`

where `!` signifies the a `rel="nofollow"` attribution?

Comment: You should have a look at [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/). It is a more recent and, I believe, easier to extend implementation of Markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference links, modify the lines around [line 733](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/b1bc42eb99bfb44b7b9d2c9f12a399a746dedd2e/markdown.php#L733) (at the time of writing) to add `nofollow` if appropriate. For inline links, modify [line 752](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/b1bc42eb99bfb44b7b9d2c9f12a399a746dedd2e/markdown.php#L752).

The reference link code currently looks like this:

```php
$url = $this->urls[$link_id];
$url = $this->encodeAttribute($url);

$result = "<a href=\"$url\"";
if ( isset( $this->titles[$link_id] ) ) {
    $title = $this->titles[$link_id];
    $title = $this->encodeAttribute($title);
    $result .=  " title=\"$title\"";
}

$link_text = $this->runSpanGamut($link_text);
$result .= ">$link_text</a>";
$result = $this->hashPart($result);
```

The inline link code looks similar. You'll want to add a check for if `$url` begins with `!` and if so, strip it and put `rel="nofollow"` at the right place in `$result`.